# Trying to upgrade from Gradle 4.10 to 5.0, but am getting unresolved references errors

Tags: gradle, dependencies, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade to Gradle 5, but am getting "Unresolved reference" errors when compiling - most of which are internal libraries that are within a classpath. Additionally, the javax.inject library somehow doesn't exist anymore.

I've tried individually adding in the libraries that are now missing, but it then fails to build for some reason (with some sort of abstract method error).

```
buildscript {
...
  dependencies {
    classpath "some-internal-classpath"
  }
}
```

How do I get it so that Gradle 5 will be able to resolve those references from my internal classpath + have javax.inject again?

Comment: It's hard to help without posting the build script I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not sure if the rest of the file would be too relevant. Most the errors being thrown are saying that some internal class doesn't exist. It seems fairly similar to https://github.com/onfido/onfido-android-sdk/issues/48 but I'm not sure what they did to fix it.

Comment: Actually you are right - after redoing this more carefully (keeping track of what dependencies are missing) and explicitly including them, my build succeeded. It was not something that could be helped without knowledge of my gradle file/internal dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When upgrading to Gradle 5.x from Gradle 4.x, there is one change in behaviour that can cause what you observe:

- Gradle 5.x will honour the [compile / runtime separation of dependency declarations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html#rel5.0:pom_compile_runtime_separation) in POM files. This means that a transitive library that is in the `runtime` scope of Maven is no longer visible at compilation.

So the fix is usually to find out the libraries you were using in your code but did not depend upon explicitly.

A useful method for doing that investigation is to leverage the `dependencies` task of Gradle, focused on the `compileClasspath`, effectively running `./gradlew dependencies --configuration compileClasspath` with Gradle 4.x and 5.x and analysing the differences.